# Recursive RegEx in .NET? (?R)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

When I use [`(?R)`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) in a RegEx pattern in .NET, I get an ArgumentException:

> Unrecognized grouping construct.

Does [`(?R)`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) this have a different syntax in .NET?

Comment: You can use [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrecurse.html) to see what language has what features by making use of the combobox above. .NET is listed as not being able to support `(?R)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing to recursion that .NET has to offer for Regex is [balancing group definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition). Recursion is not directly supported in .NET.

Comment: It's too bad it's not supported... However, with a balancing group definition I can do what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx), `(?R)` is not a valid construct in .NET regular expressions, nor is there any mention on that page of "recursive" or "recursion" so apparently this is not supported in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

.NET doesn't support RegEX recursion but you can check [this project](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net) to use PCRE in .NET
I hope it will be implemented in `System.Text.RegularExpressions` asap