# Regex match when there could be matches within

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not too experienced with regex, and I can't figure out how to get the match I want. Suppose you have the string

> This is some text here. {p1:This is some inner text{\s1:even more
>   inner!}{l1:blah}} and {l1:another}

What I want to do is match anything that starts with an open curly brace and ends with a closed curly brace. A match could have an inner open/close curly brace. The above string should have 2 matches:

```
{p1:This is some inner text{\s1:even more inner!}{l1:blah}}
{l1:another}
```

I've spent like an hour at regexr.com trying things like
    `{\\?\D\d:(.|({.*}))*}`

but at this point I'm super confused.

Comment: Do you really need to do this with regex?

Comment: What environment are you implementing this in?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I suppose I don't, but since I've started down this path I was curious.

Comment: @CertainPerformance C#

Comment: Curiosity, although valuable in general, isn't a great motivator for practical, answerable questions of the type SO is trying to collate. If you have options other than regex, use them and move on.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952113/how-can-i-match-nested-brackets-using-regex work for you?

Comment: @jammann C# does not support recursive patterns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239065/recursive-regex-in-net-r

Comment: .NET doesn't support Perl subroutine calls but one could find the same functionality using .NET *balancing groups*. Please see the dupe.