# regex to match comma delimited balanced square brackets having recursion

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

I'd like a regex to match comma-delimited, balanced square brackets where the contents of the square brackets might be comma-delimited balanced square brackets themselves.

Here are some examples:

```
example 1
input = "[abc],[def]"
groups 
    group 1 = "abc"
    group 2 = "def"

example 2
input = "[[ghi],[jkl]],[mno[pqr]],[[stu]]"
groups
    group 1 = "[ghi],[jkl]"
    group 2 = "mno[pqr]"
    group 3 = "[stu]"
```

So note that in the second example, "ghi" and "jkl" are not their own groups.  I don't need to recurse all the way down, I just need a regex to find the "level 0" groups.

Comment: Please add your current expression to see where the  issue is.

Comment: Do you have to use a regex?

Comment: @juharr - not necessarily.  I need c# code that will accomplish this parsing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I have no good starting point.  I threw a few regexes together and all were miserable failures =)

Comment: Please at least show the latest one to see where we could start off.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - here you go!  `\[(?:[^\]\[]*(?R)?)*+\]`   Although not sure if this will work in .NET

Comment: If you tried a recursive regex then why do you say "I don't need to recurse all the way down"? Surely, a PCRE regex won't work in .NET.

Comment: The regex would killing, `^\[(?<g>(?:[^][,]|\[[^][,]*])+(?:,(?:[^][,]|\[[^][,]*])+)*)](?:,\[(?<g>(?:[^][,]|\[[^][,]*])+(?:,(?:[^][,]|\[[^][,]*])+)*)])*\$`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5c%5b%28%3f%3cg%3e%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%5d%5b%2c%5d%7c%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%2c%5d*%5d%29%2b%28%3f%3a%2c%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%5d%5b%2c%5d%7c%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%2c%5d*%5d%29%2b%29*%29%5d%28%3f%3a%2c%5c%5b%28%3f%3cg%3e%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%5d%5b%2c%5d%7c%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%2c%5d*%5d%29%2b%28%3f%3a%2c%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%5d%5b%2c%5d%7c%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%2c%5d*%5d%29%2b%29*%29%5d%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=%5babc%5d%2c%5bdef%5d&o=m).

Comment: You would need to grab all captures inside `match.Groups["g"].Captures`. And note it only supports one level of recursion. Surely, it can be written in a more concise way in the C# code (since it is basically repeating `(?:[^][,]|\[[^][,]*])+`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - The first regex you uposted with recusion works great!  Unfortunately it's not supported in .NET (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239065/recursive-regex-in-net-r).  Thanks so much for your help!  I'm working thru your other solutions right now...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - When I said "I don't need to recurse all the way down" I meant that once the first set of balancing brackets was found, I don't need to further evaluate the matches.  Of course I'm free to do it by calling the Regex again on each of the matches, but I don't need a Regex that evaluates any further than the first set (outer most) brackets.  So in Example 2, Group 1 does not need to be further separated by the same Regex.  I can call the same regex again if I choose to on that group.

Comment: So, juharr suggestion should suffice. With regex, it is certainly possible, but will be too long and "workaroundish".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Your second solution with link to RegexStorm seems to work really well!  I'm putting it thru some more extensive testing and will let you know.

Comment: I am not a very slow laptop now,  I see there is a typo in the comment, when I removed `\r?` the backslash remained. The `\$` must be of course `$`. The crazy regex that will do what you need is `^\[(?<g>(?:\[(?>[^][,]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))]|[^][,])+(?:,(?:\[(?>[^][,]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))]|[^][,])+)*)](?:,\[(?<g>(?:\[(?>[^][,]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))]|[^][,])+(?:,(?:\[(?>[^][,]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))]|[^][,])+)*)])*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - That last one works great overall but does breakdown if a throw a comma into square brackets.  Consider this, which does work:  `[abc[[def ghi jkl]] mno pqr]`  now consider `[abc[[def ,ghi jkl]] mno pqr]` which does not work.  So the overall idea is that it doesn't matter what's inside the square brackets.  It's about identifying the outer-layer of square brackets which may consist of a single one `[anything here]` or multiple ones `[anything here],[anything here]`

Comment: Ok, `^\[(?<g>(?:\[(?>[^][]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))]|[^][,])+(?:,(?:\[(?>[^][]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))]|[^][,])+)*)](?:,\[(?<g>(?:\[(?>[^][]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))]|[^][,])+(?:,(?:\[(?>[^][]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))]|[^][,])+)*)])*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I accepted the posted answer.  I think regex is the wrong tool for this problem but I certainly admire your efforts on this one!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - looks like we posted a comment at the same time.  I'll try your latest Regex and let you know!

Comment: I am not going to post it anyway, let it be here in the comment section just for "educational" purposes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew- It worked great (I beat it up with like 800 generated strings)!  I think you should post it as an answer because it's a correct solution and I'd like to upvote to give you the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that can get you started on how to parse those values out.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitSquareBraketByComma(string input)
{
    int start = 0;
    int brakets = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if(input[i] == '[') 
        {
            brakets++;
            continue;
        }

        if(input[i] == ']')
        {
            brakets--;
            continue;
        }

        if(brakets == 0 && input[i] == ',')
        {
            yield return input.Substring(start, i - start);
            start = i + 1;
        }
    }

    if(start < input.Length)
    {
        yield return input.Substring(start);
    }
}
```

It basically keeps count of the brackets and when it sees a comma when the number of open brackets is zero it splits out a new string from the previous split.

Note: this does not have any code to check that the input is valid (having all balanced brackets) and thus it's leaving in the outer most brackets just in case.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, this approach is 10x faster than the regex when tested with a bunch of strings.

Comment: @SFun28 Regex solutions are almost always slower than a solution that uses string methods (assuming it's done efficiently).  The trick is to determine when to make the trade off.  It's usually when the code would be much more complicated than the regex.